# Getting error while a signed apk

Tags: android, signed-apk

gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "se.btcx.wallet"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 327
            versionName "4.59.1-btcx"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        dexOptions {
            jumboMode true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            release {
            }
            innerTest {
                matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
            }
        }

        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'// for multipart API

        aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
        aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

    //    compileOptions {
    //        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    //        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    //    }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.force 'junit:junit:4.11'
        }
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        // implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout_navigationdrawer:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.+'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        /* compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
                            compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
                                exclude module: "httpclient"
                            }*/
        /*compile files('libs/okhttp-2.1.0.jar')
                                compile files('libs/okhttp-urlconnection-2.1.0.jar')
                                compile files('libs/okio-1.1.0.jar')*/
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
        compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
        compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
        compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.2'
        compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
        // compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
        //    compile 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.14.4'
        //noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
        compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6') {
            exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
        }
        compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6'
        compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.7.5'
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
        //Logging
        // compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
        // compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'
        compile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'
        compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0'
        compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.58.0.0'
        compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0'
        compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pg:1.54.0.0'
        compile 'net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0'
        implementation files('libs/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar')
        compile 'org.bitcoinj:orchid:1.2.1'
        compile 'net.java.openjfx.backport:openjfx-78-backport-compat:1.8.0.1'
    }
```

At the time of generating signed apk, I got the following error

> Error:trouble processing "java/beans/PropertyVetoException.class":
>
> Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or
>   javax.*)
>
> Error:when not building a core library.
>
> Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
>
> Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
>
> Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
>
> Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
>
> Error:going on.
>
> Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a
>   core
>
> Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
>
> Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
>
> Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
>
> Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
>
> Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
>
> Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>
> Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
>
> Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
>
> Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>
> Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
>
> Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your
>   application
>
> Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
>
> Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
>
> Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
>
> Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
>
> Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
>
> Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
>
> Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
>
> Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be
>   in
>
> Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may
>   help
>
> Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
>
> Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
>
> Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
>
> Error:1 error; aborting
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithPreDexForRelease'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex 'C:\Users\shaileshp.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.openjfx.backport\openjfx-78-backport-compat\1.8.0.1\7cb8f4c47f25736b099d0db2a0c518e909ed6e4d\openjfx-78-backport-compat-1.8.0.1.jar' to 'D:\AndroidStudioProjects\BTCX_V9\app\build\intermediates\transforms\preDex\release\27'

Comment: have you tried to rebuild/clean the project?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to use an API which is not a part of Android SDK but Java. Could you recheck ?

Answer (score 0):

This is **bit well known** issue we face while generating sign apk

check following blog you might get out of your issue

http://jmlinnik.blogspot.in/2015/07/android-studio-android-ill-advised-or.html